# Array of total even numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, integer

Sorry, I'm still learning how to code. My question is very simple.
I'm trying to make an array of int that sum the total of even numbers. My issue is for some reason my code is counting 1 as an even number.

```
            int[] nums = new[] { 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 25, 40 };
            int even = 0;
            int odd = 0;
            for (int i =0 ; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    even += nums[i];                    
                }

                else
                {
                    odd += nums[i];                   
                }
            }
                Console.WriteLine(even);
                Console.WriteLine(odd);
```

The output will be:
59
and
39

Comment: The sum of the odd numbers is more interesting: `1, 1+3=4, 1+3+5=9, 1+3+5+7=16, 1+3+5+7+9=25` and the rest of the squares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking the parity of the loop index `i`. Use `nums[i]` in your `for` loop instead:

```cs
if (nums[i] % 2 == 0)
// ... rest of code
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the replies that others have given, you could make the code more efficient by just checking the last bit.  Basically, the last bit of the odd numbers will always be 1 so you could do something like

```
if ((nums[i] & 1) == 0)...
```

An and operation is normally a lot faster than a unoptimised % operation, which does division and then works out the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Hey in your code in `if()` condition u are checking index but but need to check
arrays values like `nums[i] ==>` will give array having values

Your code `if (i % 2 == 0)`

in place, if index just change it to `nums[i]%2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop:

```
        foreach (var num in nums)
        {
            if (num % 2 == 0)
            {
                even += num;                    
            }
            else
            {
                odd += num;                   
            }
        }
```